# How do I vary between how much froth for each coffee drink?

Tags: milk, steamed-milk, foamed-milk

I was always taught that for flat white and lattes they need 1cm of foam and for cappuccinos 2cm of foam and I can vary between these by counting from 6 - 10 (more time = more froth)

I was also taught that I can vary between the temperature of the milk for how much froth I need either between 25 - 35C

Which one is better and which one should I rely on?